# Are BWT brand water softeners "auto"?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-softener

I'm planning to buy a water softener (I'm UK based).

From what I understand there are two broad types; "Electric/timer driven" and "Non-electric/automatic", the main difference being that *"[electric softeners work on an electric timer while non-electric systems work on a meter that turns as the water flows through it](https://www.clearwatersystems.com/electric-vs-non-electric-water-softener-systems/)"*

The above linked article suggests that non-electric softeners are far more resource efficient because they soften as much water is needed, with no excess, and with no periods of softened water being unavailable (because it's all been used up before the next cycle).

A popular brand that keeps coming up in my searches is [BWT](https://www.bwtshop.co.uk/product/luxury-water-softeners/).  In particular the [WS555](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B077ZMMQJV/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1) is what I'm looking at.  They claim to be "efficient and fully automatic" but they are also electric...  but information is scattered and there doesn't appear to be a definitive answer, so I'm a little confused by what type of softener this is...

- Amazon lists it as a "‎Hi Flow Electronic Demand Block/Tablet Water Softener"
- From the [FAQs](https://www.bwt.com/en-gb/products-for-the-home/water-for-your-home/water-softener/): [...] use a 'Plug In' type transformer. The low voltage system is used to power the electronic control system and the valve during regeneration. The result is a water softener that can be set up to suit your local water conditions and that can adapt to your lifestyle. The electricity used is minimal
- [manuals](https://www.bwt.com/en-gb/-/media/bwt/uk/downloads---current-models/installation-and-operating-manuals/bwt-bestsoft-water-softener.pdf?rev=e2c0a3be82fc4ac58f557f9a69764eec) found on the website suggest some kind of "intelligent" system

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>*Every* water softener is going to require electricity because they all have internal pumps that push water into the salt tank to make the brine, then pump the brine into the media tank to clean it, then pump it back out of the media tank. This doesn't happen by magic.</s>

Apparently, it can happen by magic - I was completely unaware of softeners that simply use the water pressure already in the plumbing to move the water in and out of the tanks. If you're looking for a totally non-electric solution, it seems you should move on from the model you've mentioned and keep looking - they are made, but may not be available in the UK.

---

I have had a demand-based water softener for about a decade. It is also electric, as it requires a plug in to provide power to the computer that counts the water used and drives the regeneration cycle. To be honest, I don't recall now whether it uses more or less salt than the prior one did, but we go through about one 40lb bag of salt a month, so there's not a lot of usage. Yes, it does burn some electricity, but so do the four monitors sitting on my desk right now....

Without having looked at the documentation you've provided, the "intelligent" system knows how much water a freshly cleaned media tank can soften, based on the hardness level you program into it. (You'll have to test/have tested your water to determine how hard it is - the test will report back a number.) The other part of the "intelligent" system is a simple impeller that counts how many gallons have flowed through the softener since the last recharge cycle. When the number of gallons used is greater than the ability of the media tank to soften (or, possibly, within a certain percentage of max), then the "intelligent" system kicks off a regeneration cycle either immediately, or at the next allowed time of day. (Ours, for example, runs at 2am because there's almost never anyone awake at that time of day to use water.)

If you're looking for a completely non-electric water treatment system, the best you're going to do is some filters to clean the local contaminants out of the water stream. They are not, however, going to actually soften the water.

Comment: Your opening statement is incorrect. [Some brands](https://www.kinetico.com/water-softeners/) are completely non-electric.

Comment: Interesting, @isherwood, I wonder how they manage to pump water in & out of the media tanks without an electrically operated pump. Maybe some sort of turbo charger type technology where water flow spins an impeller that then drives the pumping action on the other side...

Comment: Couldn't say. All I know is that I hear about them on the radio. :)

Comment: Per the non-electric softeners, the one brand we had (left it in the house we sold as part of the deal), it used water pressure to drive the recharging.  There were two resin tanks, so once one was used up, it switched to the other to supply soft water to the house while it recharged that prior one.  Then switched again when the now running tank was measured as used up.

Comment: One drawback for the non-electric units are that the recharge can occur at any time of day or night, the recharge can be a somewhat noisy process (water rushing thru the resin tanks, etc). You normally won't notice that for an electric timer unit since the recharge is usually set to run at 2am or so.

Comment: Water isn't pumped in a non-electric softener.  There is no need as water pressure is all that is needed.  Just look at any softener sales blurb.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  My main concern is having "interruption of service" and I had simply assumed that non-electric softeners were the solution to this.  Whereas, these "dual tank" ones seem to address that problem (and also happen to be non-electric) https://www.eastmidlandswater.com/water-softener-harveys-crown-non-electric-block-salt-softener-f15slt/2527